# Angular template versioning

Tags: angularjs, version, single-page-application, browser-cache

I observed that often unexpected issues occurs with my apps as the user has templates cached in browser. 
I tried `$window.location.reload(true)` but even then chrome serves templates from the cache.

Is there an easy solution for this like adding a version query parameter to template URL dynamically using something like Interceptor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although on other similar question people sugested to use `$templateCache` and load everything in one go. This isn't the solution I was looking for as it would increase app first load time by increasing app size and sacrifing on lazy loading provided by angular-ui-router.

So, below is what I did.
Created a value provider for which contains version.
This file is minified and include in index page and thus gets loaded along with the page.

```
angular.module('my-app').value('version', 'X.X.X');
```

I noticed that all my templateUrl in states, directives and even in ng-include is loaded via `$http` service and thus at time of fetching template I can inject a query parameter. So I added following lines in app's config block:

```
angular.module('my-app').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', 'version', function($q, version) {
        return {
            'request': function (request) {
                if (request.url.substr(-5) == '.html') {
                    request.params = {
                        v: version
                    }
                }
                return $q.resolve(request);
            }
        }
    }]);
}]);
```

So, all my templates are called with version number and now browser waits for new template to load if version is increased.
I periodically check for version update via an api. And if a new version is detected, I prompt user to reload the page. On user approval, I reload it via `$window.location.reload(true)`

**Update**

Following is snippet to check for new version. It can vary according to use case. As we have ad-hoc release cycle here, we check for new version on each window focus and also during first load.

```
angular.module('my-app').run(['$rootScope', '$window', 'version', 'configService', function($rootScope, $window, version, configService){
    $rootScope.checkVersion = function () {
        configService.getVersion().then(function (data) {
            if (data.version != version) {
                // show user a message that new version is available
                promptUserForReload().then(function () {
                    $window.location.reload(true);
                })
            }
        });
    }

    $window.addEventListener("focus", $rootScope.checkVersion);

    $rootScope.checkVersion();
}])
```

Comment: Thanks Pushkar it worked like a charm can u also share the code how your periodically check for version

Comment: Hi Abdul, I have updated my answer with code snippet.

Comment: @Pushkar I tried your method. It works nice but i get not found errors on library templates like uib-bootstrap. Seems like they are being pulled from template cache.

Comment: @Khaleel it would help if you could give a plunkr link for the issue as I haven't used ui bootstrap.

Comment: @Khaleel you can also change condition in config to limit the templates by url on which this has to be run.

Comment: @Pushkar Forgot to post the update. I fixed it by adding conditions in config. Thanks.

Comment: @Khaleel How did you add the config condition? I'm asking cause I've run into the same problem with ui bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Without interceptor u can just add post fix version variable to template url. templateUrl:'scripts/apps/blabla.html?version?ver='+version

Comment: But then I will have to do this for all template urls and may run into issue if missed somewhere. Also, all devs working on the projects has to be told to follow this pattern.