# Handle version of files in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, version, assets, browser-cache

I would like to know if exists any way to add a suffix like

```
'app/account/script.js?v=1.0',
'app/account/style.css?v=1.0',
```

to all requests in AngularJS, including to css and js files.

Using interceptors we can do something like this 
[Angular template versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901237/angular-template-versioning)

But unforntunelly that isn't a solution for me.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly, I want to invalidate browser cache using AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this

First in your app.js

```
app.value('version', '1.0.0');
```

then we add a new directive

```
app.directive('disableCache', function(version) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            attr.$set("src", attr.src +  "#v=" + version);
        }
    };
});
```

and we update our html

```
<script src="scripts/js/filters.js" disable-cache></script>
```

and will be

```
<script src="scripts/js/filters.js#v=1.0.0" disable-cache=""></script>
```